# Can I call from one domain BL to another domain DAL?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, soa

In SOA, Can I call from one domain Business component to another domain DAL?
or should I go through that second component's BC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always go through the second BC.  If your services start sharing databases then you will have the coupling that you are trying to get rid of by doing SOA in the first place.  People often overlook database coupling when designing their services.  I know it's tempting to take that short cut sometimes, but this is something you need to be strict about.